# How to write mobile links so they open in an app on Android and iOS if that app exists, but use http link if app does not?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, windows-phone, linkedin-api

I've seen a lot of questions around this issue, but always for a specific platform or use case. I'm wondering how a link, for instance to a facebook page, should be created so that it will open in an app if available (facebook, linkedin, etc) on both iOS and Android (and Windows phone, Blackberry, etc), but will open in the browser if no app is available?

Answer (score 0):

What we use currently is an activity with this:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:scheme="@string/deeplink.scheme"
            android:host="@string/deeplink.host"
        />
    </intent-filter>
```

with

```
<string name="deeplink.scheme" translatable="false">http</string>
<string name="deeplink.host"   translatable="false">something.com</string>
```

Then in the activity we check whether the activity was started from a url:

```
protected boolean startedExternally() {
    return
        (getIntent() != null) &&
        (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(getIntent().getAction()) &&
        (getIntent().getData() != null));
}
```

and then if that returns true:

```
String route = getIntent().getData().getPath();
```

And then we do some magic to analyze the route, so the app knows what to do with it.

The intent-filter at the top determines whether or not we want the app to intercept the url, or have Android do it (which probably means to start a browser).

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look into [Bolts Framework](https://github.com/BoltsFramework).

It implements the [AppLinks protocol](http://applinks.org/documentation/).

Bolts recommended by Facebook and FacebookSDK itself based on it.

Please check the following examples:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android